# There is any kind of research on the use of a "Light-Gas Gun" on the production of Metallic Hydrogen?

Tags: pressure, research-level, hydrogen

Well, if it was that simple, there would already be some research on it, but I couldn't find any.

- **Light-Gas Gun:**

If you don't know, a Light-Gas Gun is basically an apparatus that is able to shot projectiles at hypersonic speeds (above mach 5, but they shot projectiles at the double and even triple of that value). It is used  to make studies on the high-impact phenomena, like the role of meteorites on earth's formation and a test bed for space rocket protection.

[Here is an article on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-gas_gun).

Well, the way it works is fairly simple: a solid propellant (such as gunpowder) is used to propel a pistol that compresses a light gas (such as hydrogen, helium and even methane) into a chamber that finally propels a small projectile.

[image]

- **Metallic Hydrogen:**

Maybe I'm not being quite logical here, but to me, it seems possible that such apparatus, with high enough power, could compress hydrogen enough to stay in a metallic state. And on the wikipedia article I just linked, this is said, **but it doesn't have a source** (so it is probably just an incorrect information).

Anyway, I tried to search for anything related to the use of such extreme compression on the production of metallic Hydrogen, **but I couldn't find anything**.

Or simply put, there isn't any major investigation on the subject simply because the math don't match? Let's say, it would require such tremenduous amount of energy that it wouldn't be feasible.

But I don't understand much about the subject to even check such thing.